# trying to get photo on left form in middle and text on right.

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm new to css/html/javascript and i am trying to figure out a way to get a photo on the left of my form and have text on the right of my form. ive been trying to fiddle with thing for a bit as to not bother you guys but i cant seem to figure it out. at this point i have the text on the right but when i try to add a photo to the left it doesn't work. it either ends up above my form or to the left of the form and then my text is on top. of the form.

here is some of the code i'm working with:
contactarea{

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 490px;
padding:0;
}
#contact-area input, #contact-area textarea {
float:left;
clear:both;
font-family:"ledger-regular";
padding: 5px;
width: 480px;
margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
font-size: 1.4em;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 3px;
}

#contact-area textarea {
height: 90px;
}

#contact-area textarea:focus, #contact-area input:focus {
outline:none;
border: 2px solid #D7B740;
}

#contact-area input.submit-button {
border-radius: 3px;
border-color:#D7B740;
background-color:#D7B740;
width: 493px;
}
#rightinfo {
text-align: center;
font-family:"ledger-regular";
padding:0;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#rightinfo{ 
text-align: center;
font-family:"ledger-regular";
padding:0;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
#socmed img{
display: inline-block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 45px;
```

}

html:

```
<div id="contact-area">
            <form method="post" action="contactthanks.php">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Name"/>
                <input type="text" name="City" id="City" placeholder="City"/>
                <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" />
                <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="rightinfo">
            <p>Holiday Hours</p>
            <p>Monday-Friday: 10am-6pm</p>
            <p>Saturday: 10am-4pm</p>
            <p>Sunday: 12am-4pm</p>
        </div>
        <div id="rightinfo">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/GendronsPawn/"><img id="socmed"src="../images/facebook.png"
        onmouseover="this.src='../images/facebookclicked.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/facebook.png'" alt="facebook"/></a>
        <a href="http://stores.ebay.com/Gendron-s-Jewelry-and-Pawn?_rdc=1"><img id="socmed"src="../images/ebay.png"
            onmouseover="this.src='../images/ebayclicked.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/ebay.png'" alt="ebay"/></a>
        </div>
```

[image]

thank you for the help in advance. everyone on here has been super helpful lately

Answer (score 3):

First of all, do not put the same id for two elements. An id must be unique in your html document.

Concerning the question, probably the best approach for a complete beginner is using a good framework, like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Let me explain the principles behind your question. Firstly, you could wrap your html chunks into different divs, and put them in sequence. So, it could be:

```
<div id="contact-area">

    <div id="leftinfo" class="innerdivs">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/GendronsPawn/"><img id="socmed"src="../images/facebook.png"
            onmouseover="this.src='../images/facebookclicked.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/facebook.png'" alt="facebook"/></a>
            <a href="http://stores.ebay.com/Gendron-s-Jewelry-and-Pawn?_rdc=1"><img id="socmed"src="../images/ebay.png"
                onmouseover="this.src='../images/ebayclicked.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/ebay.png'" alt="ebay"/></a>
    </div>

    <div id="forminfo"  class="innerdivs">
        <form method="post" action="contactthanks.php">
                    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Name"/>
                    <input type="text" name="City" id="City" placeholder="City"/>
                    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" />
                    <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
                </div>
         </form>
    </div>

    <div id="rightinfo" class="innerdivs">
        <p>Holiday Hours</p>
        <p>Monday-Friday: 10am-6pm</p>
        <p>Saturday: 10am-4pm</p>
        <p>Sunday: 12am-4pm</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, you could do in CSS:

```
#contact-area .innerdivs{float:left;width:33%;}
```

Note that float only work together with a width. This is the easier way to get the divs in the way you want, side by side.

A final rule is not to use id css rules for repeated elements. Note the way I made a class (innerdivs) for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure to add this at the top of your HTML:

```
<div class="photo-left">
  <img src="https://media2.5amily.com/prev_cache/60830a68cb8bf288482104d220318cda5831f7bf.jpg" class="illustration">
</div>
```

Then, add the following class definitions in your CSS file:

```
.photo-left {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 33%;
}
```

If you don't want a mug with Rhode Island humor, choose another image file. If it still doesn't work, maybe add a width: 100% to the overall container DIV (add one if you don't already have one), and/or change the widths of the other two columns to 33% also.

Good luck!